# Unit Testable Monogame: Best approach?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, architecture, monogame

I'm trying to set up a framework on top of monogame. I'd really like the framework to be unit-testable.

For example, I've written a `SpriteComponent` class. It'd be good if I could create a quick test verifying that the component's `OffsetType` property works. Something like:

```
[Fact]
public void SpriteOffsetTypeWorks()
{
    AminoGame game = new AminoGame();
    Scene scene = new Scene(game);
    Entity entity = new Entity(scene);
    SpriteComponent sprite = new SpriteComponent(entity);

    sprite.OffsetType = AnchorType.Centre;
    Assert.Equal(new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f), sprite.OffsetFactor);
}
```

For context, `AminoGame` inherits from Monogame's `Game` class.

The problem is that while some services inherent in `Game` initialise correctly in a unit test, others don't, notably the `GraphicsDevice`. This makes sense, as my unit test isn't creating a graphics environment.

To try and solve this, I

1. Tried separating the view from the model: I removed all 'render' code from `SpriteComponent`, and placed it elsewhere, in a region of code which won't be invoked in a non-graphical setting.
2. Wrote an interface which wraps around `AminoGame`, but which I can also wrap around a dummy class, which I'd use in unit tests.

This approach still has problems. For example:

```
public class SpriteComponent : Component
{
    public Texture2D Texture => _texture;
    protected Texture2D _texture;

    public SpriteComponent(Entity owner) : base(owner)
    {
        if (Config.DefaultSprite == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Cannot call {nameof(SpriteComponent)} constructor with unspecified sprite: Specify a default sprite in {nameof(Config.DefaultSprite)}.");
        }
        _texture = World.Content.Load<Texture2D>(Config.DefaultSprite);
    }
}
```

I wrote my `SpriteComponent` class with the ability to load a default texture if none was specified. But `Texture2D`is a graphical object so, again, Monogame complains that there's no `GraphicsDevice` when it tries to load one.

This has me wondering: do I ever want a texture, or a 3D model, to be used in a unit test? If not, then how can I wrote `SpriteComponent` in a way that can function entirely without graphics?

But more broadly, what other services am I relying on that, unbeknownst to me, are not available in a unit test?

Is my approach here just wrong? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

So, just to be honest, I don't know monogame at all.  But I've used dozens of frameworks over the years, and most of them suck when it comes to unit tests.  The problem is, by the time you separate your code from the framework enough to unit-test it, you generally lose most of the advantage of coding in that framework.  Your code becomes very bloated, mostly because it *can't* use the framework and be unit testable.

Some frameworks have unit-testable mocks baked in (these are nice!) but not particularly common.  A quick google search leads to this: https://community.monogame.net/t/unit-testing-best-practices/2638/2, which is not particularly encouraging.  Basically, the rule of thumb for me is, if a framework requires inheritance, unit-testing will be hard (because you can't inject mocks/stubs in).  Integration testing will most likely be your best approach.